# How to put a variable into SQL code in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Sorry for my dumb question.
I programming in Access (VBA) and I’m trying to send a variable called machine into a sql code and then insert it into a table. But i have no idea how to do it. this is my code for so far:

```
Private Sub MachineToevoegen_Click()
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim Machine As String
        Machine = Machine_keuze
        SQL = "INSERT INTO Machines ([Machine]) VALUES(Machine)"
        DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    End Sub
```

If someone could help me with this it would be great.

Comment: Error message (if not add [Option Explicit](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx))? Read on vba set string variable! Read [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com) to understand why you should not concat sql strings, but use params!

Comment: You don't assign a string to `Machine`. See me edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a query where you pass the `Machine` as parameter.

For example:

```sql
PARAMETERS [prmMachine] Text (255);
INSERT INTO Machines ([Machine])
SELECT [prmMachine] AS _Machine;
```

Then, call the query in VBA:

```vb
With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
    .Parameters("[prmMachine]").Value = Machine_keuze 
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
Private Sub MachineToevoegen_Click()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Machine As String

    Machine = "Machine_keuze"
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Machines ([Machine]) VALUES('" & Machine & "')"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't show unexperienced users how to concat sql strings as they will get bitten by injections! And look at the string ;(

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I aggreed but its really hard for beginners to catch advanced queries.

Comment: Harder than catching why does `"INSERT INTO Machines ([Machine]) VALUES('" & "Machinename
containg'Quote" & "')"` (e.g "O'neil capacitor") fail?

Comment: Saying it's hard is nonsense. Just use a tempvar: `TempVars!Machine = "Machine_keuze"`, and `SQL = "INSERT INTO Machines ([Machine]) SELECT TempVars!Machine"`. 0 added lines, avoids issues with string delimiters so conceptually likely more simple for beginners